# Event prevent default javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I open my app in a new window. In this app I prevent some default events actions for my actions. But when I close the window I want activate the default event actions.

Is there a command how to restore **ALL** events back to default actions.

How I prevent an default event

```
preventDefault = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;
if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
e.returnValue = false;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to "activate" them _after_ you close the window. When it's closed, it's closed. Nothing is active in that window any more.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explenation but I actually open the content in a new Dojo dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about the same JavaScript `window` object in which you open different Dojo views - as we clarified, you could use a condition in your event handler. E.g. you have a handler function like:

```
function handleClick(e) {

  if(window._preventDefault) {

    // prevent default action

  }

  // handle event
}
```

Then you could control whether to prevent defaults globally by changing the `_preventDefault` global variable so after

```
window._preventDefault = false;
```

The assigned handlers would not prevent default but if you set that variable to `true` then they would.

Comment: Such a simple sollution and it works. I actually did it a bit different but used the concept from you. Thank you!